# Cycles and/or Multiple Cascade Paths with Auto-Generated Linking Table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have been using EF5 via Code First successfully so far to build out my database from my models. However, I recently ran into a (fairly) common issue of cycles/multiple cascade paths. I understand what the problem is and normally, I fix it by writing rules against my entities to disable CascadeOnDelete down one side of the branch. The difference with this scenario and my current one, is that I typically am creating the middle "join" table in a many-to-many relationship.

So, for example, I may have: Users => UserLeagues <= Leagues
And then I do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserLeagues>()
           .HasRequired(u => u.League)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(l => l.LeagueId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Where I have created the UserLeague table (it requires some additional information so this makes sense). In my most recent case, I just needed to create a many-to-many relationship. So, I didn't bother to create this middle table. Instead, I let EF auto-generate it.

As a result, I am unsure of how to stop the cascade delete down the one side because I don't have access to the UserLeagues table directly like I do if I manually created that many-to-many table. Any advice? Here are my models...

```
public User {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<League> Leagues { get; set; }
}

public League {
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int Score { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I'm right you're talking about the actual db-level cascade (from UserLeagues to User or League - not in between User <-> League which is sort of conceptual association cascade). I think that's 'on' because otherwise you have no way of deleting the actual records in the join table, when the relationship is removed (since you have no table mapped to entity). One way to do that if you'd like is to change the migration scripts (providing you're using that) - it has something like `.ForeignKey("dbo.Leagues", t => t.League_Id, cascadeDelete: true)`. But then you'd end up with renegate recs

Comment: And in that case - you could remove the `convention` all together (for all many to many) - e.g. `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you let EF auto-generate (many-to-many relationship and the support table) - `you have no way of manually deleting the actual records in the join table, once the relationship is removed` (since you don't have that table mapped to an entity).
Hence the **cascade deletes need to be 'on' by default**. That's '**by convention**'.

You could **remove that convention all together** (for all many to many - and their fk-s involved)...
`modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();`

Another way to do that on a `case by case` basis - would be to **change the migration scripts**
 (providing you're using migrations).

When migrations generate the pseudo code - it has something like
`.ForeignKey("dbo.Leagues", t => t.League_Id, cascadeDelete: true)`

Just remove the `, cascadeDelete: true` parameter.

But then you'll end up with `phantom records` (i.e. you'll need to resort to manual SQL or occasional cleanup to remove the junk records).